# Passing selected row to detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Evening,

I am in the process of configuring my detail view. The data is held in a plist file, each item having a word and definition. The cells in the tableview are labelled with the word. I am looking for each word to lead to the detail view showing both word and definition. 
At the moment the code is showing the wrong word. I have been trying to set word and definition in the tableview.m and then use these to set the label in detail view. 
So my query is why the wrong word is showing and how I can grab the correct definition to match the word.

My code is below. 
Thank you.

```
#import "RCViewController.h"
#import "detailViewController.h"

@interface RCViewController ()

@end

@implementation RCViewController

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@synthesize words;
@synthesize alphabetizedWords;
@synthesize wordDictionary;


-(NSDictionary *)alphabetizedWords:(NSArray *)wordsArray {
    NSMutableDictionary *buffer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i <words.count; i++) {
        NSString *word = [words objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *firstLetter = [[word substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString];

        if ([buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]) {
            [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]addObject:word];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:word, nil];
            [buffer setObject:mutableArray forKey:firstLetter];
        }
    }
    NSArray *keys = [buffer allKeys];
    for (int j; j<keys.count; j++) {
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:j];
        [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:key]sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:buffer];
    return result;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray *keys = [self.alphabetizedWords allKeys];
    return [keys count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.alphabetizedWords allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
    return  [wordsForSection count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.alphabetizedWords allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
    NSString *word = [wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell.textLabel setText:word];

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *keys = [[self.alphabetizedWords allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // perform the segue by getting the cell selected and passing it to the prepareForSegue method
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:cell];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


        detailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.word = [words objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *wordsDictionary = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    self.words = [wordsDictionary valueForKey:@"Word"];

    self.alphabetizedWords = [self alphabetizedWords:self.words];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface detailViewController : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *word;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *definitionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *definition;

@end


#import "detailViewController.h"

@interface detailViewController ()

@end

@implementation detailViewController

@synthesize word;
@synthesize wordLabel;
@synthesize definition;
@synthesize definitionLabel;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    wordLabel.text = word;
    definitionLabel.text = definition;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: GACK! Do **not** build a sorted list of your keys every time in cellForRowAtIndexPath! Very, very bad idea. If your list of words gets longer than 30 words or so performance will go to hell. Build an array of your table view data items (words) when you get ready to display your table view, and then use the pre-built array in both cellForRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue.

Comment: Thank you for that heads up - it comes from a tutorial I found but I appreciate your advice. In order to rectify this, am I right in thinking I simply need to create these as properties, set their associated values and then just refer to them in the methods?

Comment: Yup. Build a sorted array of items once, save it in a property, and then use it wherever needed.

Comment: If you found that code in a tutorial, run the other way. Seriously. That is D-U-M-B. Anybody writing code that re-sorts an array of items for every call to cellForRowAtIndexPath is lost, and will do you more harm than good. Doing that as a beginner mistake is one thing, but posting tutorials with that kind of horrible design flaw is inexcusable. Can you post a link to this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same logic in prepareForSegue to get your word that you use in cellForRowAtIndexPath,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        detailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.alphabetizedWords allKeys];
        NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
        NSString *word = [wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        destViewController.word = word;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Last thing; how's best to then match the word with the right definition. I have attempted objectatindex:[self.tableview indexpathforselectedrow].row]valueforkey:@"Definition"]; to set destination view controller definition, but it's displaying the wrong definition.

Comment: @user3692490, I don't know what your data structure is, so I can't advise you. I suspect you'll have to do something similar to what you did to get the word.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dictionary called alphabetizedWords is pretty pointless, since dictionaries are inherently unordered. You should set up your data structure in an array. Perhaps you want an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains a word in one key and the definition in the other key. You can sort the array and use to feed the table view data source, and also to respond to a tap and pass the info to your detail view controller.